# Fast way to organize hierarchical MySQL tables?

Tags: javascript, mysql, jquery-plugins, hierarchical-data

I need to create (and edit constantly) hierarchical database structure like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95654/3

so the real structure looks like this:

- a

  - b
  - c
- x

  - y

Since I need to add/remove/edit items constantly, it is a pain with phpMyAdmin, or queries.

So is there a plugin for JavaScript (Ajax) and PHP, that organizes this kind of things with drag & drop? or any other easy way?

Thanks !

*P.S.:* I know that the plugin cannot know the item table's structure, but I only need it to set parent relations (`hierarchy_table` in the example) quickly. I can add the items, and make them DOM objects. So I need drag and drop for parent relations.

for example, I can have div's for all objects that contain data like :

```
<div class='item' data-id='2' data-title='b'/>
```

and when I drag it into the div for 'a', it should insert or update the `hierarchy_table` where item_id = 2.